# Is there a rational homotopy equivalence between $\Omega S^3$ and infinite complex projective space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

The singular cohomology of the loop space $\Omega S^3$ of the 3-sphere is a divided power algebra $\Gamma_{\mathbb Z}[s]$ on one generator $s$ of degree 2, so the rational cohomology is a the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[s]$. Likewise, the singular cohomology of infinite complex projective space $\mathbb C \mathrm P^\infty = BS^1$ is a polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ on one generator $t$ of degree 2, so the rational cohomology is $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.

Since a symmetric algebra is a free CGA, any lifting of $s$ and $t$ to cocycles in CDGA models for the rational cohomology of these spaces induces a quasi-isomorphism between the cohomology ring, viewed as a CDGA with trivial differential, and the model, so these spaces are both formal. Moreover, both spaces are simply-connected. Thus any map between the two inducing an isomorphism in rational cohomology should be a rational homotopy equivalence.

**Does there exist such a map?**

P.S.: I guess the same question is equally (un)reasonable for $\Omega S^5$ and $\mathbb H \mathrm P^\infty$. What about this pair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a map $S^3\to K(\mathbb{Z},3)$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_3$.  Looping this map, you get a map $\Omega S^3\to K(\mathbb{Z},2)=\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_2$.  It follows easily that this map is a rational equivalence.

For $\Omega S^5$ and $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$, I don't know whether you can get a map $\Omega S^5\to \mathbb{H}P^\infty$ which is a rational equivalence (the above approach doesn't work because you can't deloop $\mathbb{H}P^\infty$).  However, there is no rational equivalence $\mathbb{H}P^\infty\to\Omega S^5$.  For if you had such a map, then it would be nonzero on $H^4(-,\mathbb{Z})$, and so looking at the induced map on the whole integral cohomology rings, you would get a ring-homomorphism $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}(s)\to\mathbb{Z}[t]$ sending $s$ to $nt$ for some nonzero integer $n$.  But if $p$ is a prime not dividing $n$, such a homomorphism would have nowhere to send $s^p/p!$.  (Alternatively, you could use Steenrod powers: a rational equivalence $\mathbb{H}P^\infty\to\Omega S^5$ would yield a map $\Sigma\mathbb{H}P^\infty\to S^5$ whose induced map on $H^5(-,\mathbb{Z})$ is multiplication by some nonzero integer $n$; reducing mod a prime not dividing $n$ and considering the Steenrod power $P^2$ then yields a contradiction).  Note, however, that they can easily be connected by a zigzag of rational equivalences: for instance, a map from either of them to $K(\mathbb{Z},4)$ classifying a generator of $H^4$ is a rational equivalence.

Comment: 1. Is there anything more geometric to be said about the map $\Omega S^3 \to \mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^\infty$ in question?

Comment: 2. Where does the sufficient largeness of the prime come in?

Comment: 1.  Here is one neat interpretation of it, which you may or may not consider "geometric".  By a theorem of James, the space $\Omega S^3=\Omega\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^1$ can be identified (up to homotopy) with the free topological monoid on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ (as a pointed space, with the basepoint becoming the unit of the monoid), and $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ can be identified with the free topological _commutative_ monoid on $\mathbb{C}P^1$.  This map $\Omega\Sigma \mathbb{C}P^1\to\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is then just the canonical "abelianization" map.

Comment: 2.  You just need to choose a prime $p$ such that the induced map on $H^5(-,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is nonzero.

Comment: 3. I'm obviously missing something kind of major here, so I'd better ask. The cohomology of $\mathbb{H}P^\infty = BS^3$ should be a polynomial ring on one variable of degree four, and that of $S^4$ should be a truncated polynomial ring inhabited only in degrees zero and four. Both these spaces are simply-connected. How could it be that a map between these spaces could induce an isomorphism in rational cohomology?

Comment: 1. That is a very cool interpretation.

Comment: 3. Oops, you're right; I was just being dumb.

Comment: 3. That's a relief! I was very confused.

Comment: 2. Okay, if I'm understanding right, the idea is to use the fact that the powers commute with suspension to find a nontrivial map $P^2\colon H^4(\mathbb{H}P^\infty;\mathbb{F}_p) \to H^{4p}(\mathbb{H}P^\infty;\mathbb{F}_p)$. But this should always be the $p$th-power map in degree 4, and that map should always be nontrivial because $H^*(\mathbb{H}P^\infty;\mathbb Z)$ is already a polynomial ring with integer coefficients. No?

Comment: 2. Yep, that's exactly right.

Comment: 2. Oh. The reason for $p \gg 0$ is that the map on $H^5$ is multiplication by some integer (having left the $\mathbb Q$ realm), and that integer could be divisible by several $p$. Got it. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, you could also just use the cohomology ring structure instead of Steenrod powers.  You can show there's no ring-homomorphism $\Gamma_\mathbb{Z}(s)\to\mathbb{Z}[t]$ sending $s$ to $nt$ for some $n\neq 0$ (since if you choose a prime $p$ not dividing $n$, there's nowhere to send $s^p/p!$).

Comment: True! That's why I asked only for a rational equivalence, although I guess that doesn't rule out the mystery map in the other direction. Maybe I should ask it in another question.